# pivot point lost after element move whit orbitcontrols

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a problem whit three.js and  OrbitControls.js., i have an sphere that's make a little tween from center to left,
this is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mirko_roma89/4ruLy96g/1/

```js
var scene, renderer, camera, controls;

init();
animate();

function init()
{ 

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( {antialias:true} );
  var width = window.innerWidth;
  var height = window.innerHeight;

  renderer.setSize (width, height);
  renderer.setClearColor( 0x222244, 1);

  document.body.appendChild (renderer.domElement);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera (45, width/height, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.y = 16;
  camera.position.z = 250;

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls (camera, renderer.domElement);
  controls.enableDamping = true;
  controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
    
 var gridXZ = new THREE.GridHelper(100, 10);
 gridXZ.setColors( new THREE.Color(0xff0000), new THREE.Color(0xffffff) );
 scene.add(gridXZ);

  var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  loader.crossOrigin = "";
  var earthTexture = loader.load( "http://api.usno.navy.mil/imagery/earth.png?view=full&date=11/24/2015&time=4:45", callback );

  // globe
  var radius = 100;
  var sphere = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( radius, 16,16), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: earthTexture } ) );
  scene.add( sphere );
    

  var latitude = 38.43;
  var longitude = -9.1;


  
  var marker = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 1, 16, 16 ), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFF0000 } ) );
  
  sphere.add( marker );

  var verticalOffset = 0.1;

  function callback() {

    new TWEEN.Tween( sphere.position )
    .to( { x:-30 , y: 0 }, 2000 )
    .start();

  }
    
}



function animate()
{
  requestAnimationFrame ( animate );  
  TWEEN.update();
  controls.update();
  renderer.render (scene, camera);
}
```

```html
<script>
/**
 * @author qiao / https://github.com/qiao
 * @author mrdoob / http://mrdoob.com
 * @author alteredq / http://alteredqualia.com/
 * @author WestLangley / http://github.com/WestLangley
 * @author erich666 / http://erichaines.com
 */

// This set of controls performs orbiting, dollying (zooming), and panning.
// Unlike TrackballControls, it maintains the "up" direction object.up (+Y by default).
//
//    Orbit - left mouse / touch: one finger move
//    Zoom - middle mouse, or mousewheel / touch: two finger spread or squish
//    Pan - right mouse, or arrow keys / touch: three finter swipe

THREE.OrbitControls = function ( object, domElement ) {

 this.object = object;

 this.domElement = ( domElement !== undefined ) ? domElement : document;

 // Set to false to disable this control
 this.enabled = true;

 // "target" sets the location of focus, where the object orbits around
 this.target = new THREE.Vector3();

 // How far you can dolly in and out ( PerspectiveCamera only )
 this.minDistance = 0;
 this.maxDistance = Infinity;

 // How far you can zoom in and out ( OrthographicCamera only )
 this.minZoom = 0;
 this.maxZoom = Infinity;

 // How far you can orbit vertically, upper and lower limits.
 // Range is 0 to Math.PI radians.
 this.minPolarAngle = 0; // radians
 this.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI; // radians

 // How far you can orbit horizontally, upper and lower limits.
 // If set, must be a sub-interval of the interval [ - Math.PI, Math.PI ].
 this.minAzimuthAngle = - Infinity; // radians
 this.maxAzimuthAngle = Infinity; // radians

 // Set to true to enable damping (inertia)
 // If damping is enabled, you must call controls.update() in your animation loop
 this.enableDamping = false;
 this.dampingFactor = 0.25;

 // This option actually enables dollying in and out; left as "zoom" for backwards compatibility.
 // Set to false to disable zooming
 this.enableZoom = true;
 this.zoomSpeed = 1.0;

 // Set to false to disable rotating
 this.enableRotate = true;
 this.rotateSpeed = 1.0;

 // Set to false to disable panning
 this.enablePan = true;
 this.keyPanSpeed = 7.0; // pixels moved per arrow key push

 // Set to true to automatically rotate around the target
 // If auto-rotate is enabled, you must call controls.update() in your animation loop
 this.autoRotate = false;
 this.autoRotateSpeed = 2.0; // 30 seconds per round when fps is 60

 // Set to false to disable use of the keys
 this.enableKeys = true;

 // The four arrow keys
 this.keys = { LEFT: 37, UP: 38, RIGHT: 39, BOTTOM: 40 };

 // Mouse buttons
 this.mouseButtons = { ORBIT: THREE.MOUSE.LEFT, ZOOM: THREE.MOUSE.MIDDLE, PAN: THREE.MOUSE.RIGHT };

 // for reset
 this.target0 = this.target.clone();
 this.position0 = this.object.position.clone();
 this.zoom0 = this.object.zoom;

 //
 // public methods
 //

 this.getPolarAngle = function () {

  return phi;

 };

 this.getAzimuthalAngle = function () {

  return theta;

 };

 this.reset = function () {

  scope.target.copy( scope.target0 );
  scope.object.position.copy( scope.position0 );
  scope.object.zoom = scope.zoom0;

  scope.object.updateProjectionMatrix();
  scope.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

  scope.update();

  state = STATE.NONE;

 };

 // this method is exposed, but perhaps it would be better if we can make it private...
 this.update = function() {

  var offset = new THREE.Vector3();

  // so camera.up is the orbit axis
  var quat = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromUnitVectors( object.up, new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 ) );
  var quatInverse = quat.clone().inverse();

  var lastPosition = new THREE.Vector3();
  var lastQuaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();

  return function () {

   var position = scope.object.position;

   offset.copy( position ).sub( scope.target );

   // rotate offset to "y-axis-is-up" space
   offset.applyQuaternion( quat );

   // angle from z-axis around y-axis

   theta = Math.atan2( offset.x, offset.z );

   // angle from y-axis

   phi = Math.atan2( Math.sqrt( offset.x * offset.x + offset.z * offset.z ), offset.y );

   if ( scope.autoRotate && state === STATE.NONE ) {

    rotateLeft( getAutoRotationAngle() );

   }

   theta += thetaDelta;
   phi += phiDelta;

   // restrict theta to be between desired limits
   theta = Math.max( scope.minAzimuthAngle, Math.min( scope.maxAzimuthAngle, theta ) );

   // restrict phi to be between desired limits
   phi = Math.max( scope.minPolarAngle, Math.min( scope.maxPolarAngle, phi ) );

   // restrict phi to be betwee EPS and PI-EPS
   phi = Math.max( EPS, Math.min( Math.PI - EPS, phi ) );

   var radius = offset.length() * scale;

   // restrict radius to be between desired limits
   radius = Math.max( scope.minDistance, Math.min( scope.maxDistance, radius ) );

   // move target to panned location
   scope.target.add( panOffset );

   offset.x = radius * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );
   offset.y = radius * Math.cos( phi );
   offset.z = radius * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );

   // rotate offset back to "camera-up-vector-is-up" space
   offset.applyQuaternion( quatInverse );

   position.copy( scope.target ).add( offset );

   scope.object.lookAt( scope.target );

   if ( scope.enableDamping === true ) {

    thetaDelta *= ( 1 - scope.dampingFactor );
    phiDelta *= ( 1 - scope.dampingFactor );

   } else {

    thetaDelta = 0;
    phiDelta = 0;

   }

   scale = 1;
   panOffset.set( 0, 0, 0 );

   // update condition is:
   // min(camera displacement, camera rotation in radians)^2 > EPS
   // using small-angle approximation cos(x/2) = 1 - x^2 / 8

   if ( zoomChanged ||
    lastPosition.distanceToSquared( scope.object.position ) > EPS ||
    8 * ( 1 - lastQuaternion.dot( scope.object.quaternion ) ) > EPS ) {

    scope.dispatchEvent( changeEvent );

    lastPosition.copy( scope.object.position );
    lastQuaternion.copy( scope.object.quaternion );
    zoomChanged = false;

    return true;

   }

   return false;

  };

 }();

 this.dispose = function() {

  scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'contextmenu', onContextMenu, false );
  scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false );
  scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false );
  scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'MozMousePixelScroll', onMouseWheel, false ); // firefox

  scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouchStart, false );
  scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchend', onTouchEnd, false );
  scope.domElement.removeEventListener( 'touchmove', onTouchMove, false );

  document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
  document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );
  document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onMouseUp, false );

  window.removeEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );

  //scope.dispatchEvent( { type: 'dispose' } ); // should this be added here?

 };

 //
 // internals
 //

 var scope = this;

 var changeEvent = { type: 'change' };
 var startEvent = { type: 'start' };
 var endEvent = { type: 'end' };

 var STATE = { NONE : - 1, ROTATE : 0, DOLLY : 1, PAN : 2, TOUCH_ROTATE : 3, TOUCH_DOLLY : 4, TOUCH_PAN : 5 };

 var state = STATE.NONE;

 var EPS = 0.000001;

 // current position in spherical coordinates
 var theta;
 var phi;

 var phiDelta = 0;
 var thetaDelta = 0;
 var scale = 1;
 var panOffset = new THREE.Vector3();
 var zoomChanged = false;

 var rotateStart = new THREE.Vector2();
 var rotateEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
 var rotateDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

 var panStart = new THREE.Vector2();
 var panEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
 var panDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

 var dollyStart = new THREE.Vector2();
 var dollyEnd = new THREE.Vector2();
 var dollyDelta = new THREE.Vector2();

 function getAutoRotationAngle() {

  return 2 * Math.PI / 60 / 60 * scope.autoRotateSpeed;

 }

 function getZoomScale() {

  return Math.pow( 0.95, scope.zoomSpeed );

 }

 function rotateLeft( angle ) {

  thetaDelta -= angle;

 }

 function rotateUp( angle ) {

  phiDelta -= angle;

 }

 var panLeft = function() {

  var v = new THREE.Vector3();

  return function panLeft( distance, objectMatrix ) {

   var te = objectMatrix.elements;

   // get X column of objectMatrix
   v.set( te[ 0 ], te[ 1 ], te[ 2 ] );

   v.multiplyScalar( - distance );

   panOffset.add( v );

  };

 }();

 var panUp = function() {

  var v = new THREE.Vector3();

  return function panUp( distance, objectMatrix ) {

   var te = objectMatrix.elements;

   // get Y column of objectMatrix
   v.set( te[ 4 ], te[ 5 ], te[ 6 ] );

   v.multiplyScalar( distance );

   panOffset.add( v );

  };

 }();

 // deltaX and deltaY are in pixels; right and down are positive
 var pan = function() {

  var offset = new THREE.Vector3();

  return function( deltaX, deltaY ) {

   var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;

   if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera ) {

    // perspective
    var position = scope.object.position;
    offset.copy( position ).sub( scope.target );
    var targetDistance = offset.length();

    // half of the fov is center to top of screen
    targetDistance *= Math.tan( ( scope.object.fov / 2 ) * Math.PI / 180.0 );

    // we actually don't use screenWidth, since perspective camera is fixed to screen height
    panLeft( 2 * deltaX * targetDistance / element.clientHeight, scope.object.matrix );
    panUp( 2 * deltaY * targetDistance / element.clientHeight, scope.object.matrix );

   } else if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera ) {

    // orthographic
    panLeft( deltaX * ( scope.object.right - scope.object.left ) / element.clientWidth, scope.object.matrix );
    panUp( deltaY * ( scope.object.top - scope.object.bottom ) / element.clientHeight, scope.object.matrix );

   } else {

    // camera neither orthographic nor perspective
    console.warn( 'WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - pan disabled.' );
    scope.enablePan = false;

   }

  };

 }();

 function dollyIn( dollyScale ) {

  if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera ) {

   scale /= dollyScale;

  } else if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera ) {

   scope.object.zoom = Math.max( scope.minZoom, Math.min( scope.maxZoom, scope.object.zoom * dollyScale ) );
   scope.object.updateProjectionMatrix();
   zoomChanged = true;

  } else {

   console.warn( 'WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - dolly/zoom disabled.' );
   scope.enableZoom = false;

  }

 }

 function dollyOut( dollyScale ) {

  if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.PerspectiveCamera ) {

   scale *= dollyScale;

  } else if ( scope.object instanceof THREE.OrthographicCamera ) {

   scope.object.zoom = Math.max( scope.minZoom, Math.min( scope.maxZoom, scope.object.zoom / dollyScale ) );
   scope.object.updateProjectionMatrix();
   zoomChanged = true;

  } else {

   console.warn( 'WARNING: OrbitControls.js encountered an unknown camera type - dolly/zoom disabled.' );
   scope.enableZoom = false;

  }

 }

 //
 // event callbacks - update the object state
 //

 function handleMouseDownRotate( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleMouseDownRotate' );

  rotateStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

 }

 function handleMouseDownDolly( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleMouseDownDolly' );

  dollyStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

 }

 function handleMouseDownPan( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleMouseDownPan' );

  panStart.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

 }

 function handleMouseMoveRotate( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleMouseMoveRotate' );

  rotateEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );
  rotateDelta.subVectors( rotateEnd, rotateStart );

  var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;

  // rotating across whole screen goes 360 degrees around
  rotateLeft( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / element.clientWidth * scope.rotateSpeed );

  // rotating up and down along whole screen attempts to go 360, but limited to 180
  rotateUp( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / element.clientHeight * scope.rotateSpeed );

  rotateStart.copy( rotateEnd );

  scope.update();

 }

 function handleMouseMoveDolly( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleMouseMoveDolly' );

  dollyEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

  dollyDelta.subVectors( dollyEnd, dollyStart );

  if ( dollyDelta.y > 0 ) {

   dollyIn( getZoomScale() );

  } else if ( dollyDelta.y < 0 ) {

   dollyOut( getZoomScale() );

  }

  dollyStart.copy( dollyEnd );

  scope.update();

 }

 function handleMouseMovePan( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleMouseMovePan' );

  panEnd.set( event.clientX, event.clientY );

  panDelta.subVectors( panEnd, panStart );

  pan( panDelta.x, panDelta.y );

  panStart.copy( panEnd );

  scope.update();

 }

 function handleMouseUp( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleMouseUp' );

 }

 function handleMouseWheel( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleMouseWheel' );

  var delta = 0;

  if ( event.wheelDelta !== undefined ) {

   // WebKit / Opera / Explorer 9

   delta = event.wheelDelta;

  } else if ( event.detail !== undefined ) {

   // Firefox

   delta = - event.detail;

  }

  if ( delta > 0 ) {

   dollyOut( getZoomScale() );

  } else if ( delta < 0 ) {

   dollyIn( getZoomScale() );

  }

  scope.update();

 }

 function handleKeyDown( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleKeyDown' );

  switch ( event.keyCode ) {

   case scope.keys.UP:
    pan( 0, scope.keyPanSpeed );
    scope.update();
    break;

   case scope.keys.BOTTOM:
    pan( 0, - scope.keyPanSpeed );
    scope.update();
    break;

   case scope.keys.LEFT:
    pan( scope.keyPanSpeed, 0 );
    scope.update();
    break;

   case scope.keys.RIGHT:
    pan( - scope.keyPanSpeed, 0 );
    scope.update();
    break;

  }

 }

 function handleTouchStartRotate( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleTouchStartRotate' );

  rotateStart.set( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY );

 }

 function handleTouchStartDolly( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleTouchStartDolly' );

  var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
  var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;

  var distance = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

  dollyStart.set( 0, distance );

 }

 function handleTouchStartPan( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleTouchStartPan' );

  panStart.set( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY );

 }

 function handleTouchMoveRotate( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleTouchMoveRotate' );

  rotateEnd.set( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY );
  rotateDelta.subVectors( rotateEnd, rotateStart );

  var element = scope.domElement === document ? scope.domElement.body : scope.domElement;

  // rotating across whole screen goes 360 degrees around
  rotateLeft( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.x / element.clientWidth * scope.rotateSpeed );

  // rotating up and down along whole screen attempts to go 360, but limited to 180
  rotateUp( 2 * Math.PI * rotateDelta.y / element.clientHeight * scope.rotateSpeed );

  rotateStart.copy( rotateEnd );

  scope.update();

 }

 function handleTouchMoveDolly( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleTouchMoveDolly' );

  var dx = event.touches[ 0 ].pageX - event.touches[ 1 ].pageX;
  var dy = event.touches[ 0 ].pageY - event.touches[ 1 ].pageY;

  var distance = Math.sqrt( dx * dx + dy * dy );

  dollyEnd.set( 0, distance );

  dollyDelta.subVectors( dollyEnd, dollyStart );

  if ( dollyDelta.y > 0 ) {

   dollyOut( getZoomScale() );

  } else if ( dollyDelta.y < 0 ) {

   dollyIn( getZoomScale() );

  }

  dollyStart.copy( dollyEnd );

  scope.update();

 }

 function handleTouchMovePan( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleTouchMovePan' );

  panEnd.set( event.touches[ 0 ].pageX, event.touches[ 0 ].pageY );

  panDelta.subVectors( panEnd, panStart );

  pan( panDelta.x, panDelta.y );

  panStart.copy( panEnd );

  scope.update();

 }

 function handleTouchEnd( event ) {

  //console.log( 'handleTouchEnd' );

 }

 //
 // event handlers - FSM: listen for events and reset state
 //

 function onMouseDown( event ) {

  if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();

  if ( event.button === scope.mouseButtons.ORBIT ) {

   if ( scope.enableRotate === false ) return;

   handleMouseDownRotate( event );

   state = STATE.ROTATE;

  } else if ( event.button === scope.mouseButtons.ZOOM ) {

   if ( scope.enableZoom === false ) return;

   handleMouseDownDolly( event );

   state = STATE.DOLLY;

  } else if ( event.button === scope.mouseButtons.PAN ) {

   if ( scope.enablePan === false ) return;

   handleMouseDownPan( event );

   state = STATE.PAN;

  }

  if ( state !== STATE.NONE ) {

   document.addEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
   document.addEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );
   document.addEventListener( 'mouseout', onMouseUp, false );

   scope.dispatchEvent( startEvent );

  }

 }

 function onMouseMove( event ) {

  if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();

  if ( state === STATE.ROTATE ) {

   if ( scope.enableRotate === false ) return;

   handleMouseMoveRotate( event );

  } else if ( state === STATE.DOLLY ) {

   if ( scope.enableZoom === false ) return;

   handleMouseMoveDolly( event );

  } else if ( state === STATE.PAN ) {

   if ( scope.enablePan === false ) return;

   handleMouseMovePan( event );

  }

 }

 function onMouseUp( event ) {

  if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

  handleMouseUp( event );

  document.removeEventListener( 'mousemove', onMouseMove, false );
  document.removeEventListener( 'mouseup', onMouseUp, false );
  document.removeEventListener( 'mouseout', onMouseUp, false );

  scope.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

  state = STATE.NONE;

 }

 function onMouseWheel( event ) {

  if ( scope.enabled === false || scope.enableZoom === false || state !== STATE.NONE ) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  handleMouseWheel( event );

  scope.dispatchEvent( startEvent ); // not sure why these are here...
  scope.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

 }

 function onKeyDown( event ) {

  if ( scope.enabled === false || scope.enableKeys === false || scope.enablePan === false ) return;

  handleKeyDown( event );

 }

 function onTouchStart( event ) {

  if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

  switch ( event.touches.length ) {

   case 1: // one-fingered touch: rotate

    if ( scope.enableRotate === false ) return;

    handleTouchStartRotate( event );

    state = STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE;

    break;

   case 2: // two-fingered touch: dolly

    if ( scope.enableZoom === false ) return;

    handleTouchStartDolly( event );

    state = STATE.TOUCH_DOLLY;

    break;

   case 3: // three-fingered touch: pan

    if ( scope.enablePan === false ) return;

    handleTouchStartPan( event );

    state = STATE.TOUCH_PAN;

    break;

   default:

    state = STATE.NONE;

  }

  if ( state !== STATE.NONE ) {

   scope.dispatchEvent( startEvent );

  }

 }

 function onTouchMove( event ) {

  if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  switch ( event.touches.length ) {

   case 1: // one-fingered touch: rotate

    if ( scope.enableRotate === false ) return;
    if ( state !== STATE.TOUCH_ROTATE ) return; // is this needed?...

    handleTouchMoveRotate( event );

    break;

   case 2: // two-fingered touch: dolly

    if ( scope.enableZoom === false ) return;
    if ( state !== STATE.TOUCH_DOLLY ) return; // is this needed?...

    handleTouchMoveDolly( event );

    break;

   case 3: // three-fingered touch: pan

    if ( scope.enablePan === false ) return;
    if ( state !== STATE.TOUCH_PAN ) return; // is this needed?...

    handleTouchMovePan( event );

    break;

   default:

    state = STATE.NONE;

  }

 }

 function onTouchEnd( event ) {

  if ( scope.enabled === false ) return;

  handleTouchEnd( event );

  scope.dispatchEvent( endEvent );

  state = STATE.NONE;

 }

 function onContextMenu( event ) {

  event.preventDefault();

 }

 //

 scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'contextmenu', onContextMenu, false );

 scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onMouseDown, false );
 scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'mousewheel', onMouseWheel, false );
 scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'MozMousePixelScroll', onMouseWheel, false ); // firefox

 scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchstart', onTouchStart, false );
 scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchend', onTouchEnd, false );
 scope.domElement.addEventListener( 'touchmove', onTouchMove, false );

 window.addEventListener( 'keydown', onKeyDown, false );

 // force an update at start

 this.update();

};

THREE.OrbitControls.prototype = Object.create( THREE.EventDispatcher.prototype );
THREE.OrbitControls.prototype.constructor = THREE.OrbitControls;

Object.defineProperties( THREE.OrbitControls.prototype, {

 center: {

  get: function () {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .center has been renamed to .target' );
   return this.target;

  }

 },

 // backward compatibility

 noZoom: {

  get: function () {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noZoom has been deprecated. Use .enableZoom instead.' );
   return ! this.enableZoom;

  },

  set: function ( value ) {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noZoom has been deprecated. Use .enableZoom instead.' );
   this.enableZoom = ! value;

  }

 },

 noRotate: {

  get: function () {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noRotate has been deprecated. Use .enableRotate instead.' );
   return ! this.enableRotate;

  },

  set: function ( value ) {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noRotate has been deprecated. Use .enableRotate instead.' );
   this.enableRotate = ! value;

  }

 },

 noPan: {

  get: function () {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noPan has been deprecated. Use .enablePan instead.' );
   return ! this.enablePan;

  },

  set: function ( value ) {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noPan has been deprecated. Use .enablePan instead.' );
   this.enablePan = ! value;

  }

 },

 noKeys: {

  get: function () {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noKeys has been deprecated. Use .enableKeys instead.' );
   return ! this.enableKeys;

  },

  set: function ( value ) {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .noKeys has been deprecated. Use .enableKeys instead.' );
   this.enableKeys = ! value;

  }

 },

 staticMoving : {

  get: function () {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .staticMoving has been deprecated. Use .enableDamping instead.' );
   return ! this.constraint.enableDamping;

  },

  set: function ( value ) {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .staticMoving has been deprecated. Use .enableDamping instead.' );
   this.constraint.enableDamping = ! value;

  }

 },

 dynamicDampingFactor : {

  get: function () {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .dynamicDampingFactor has been renamed. Use .dampingFactor instead.' );
   return this.constraint.dampingFactor;

  },

  set: function ( value ) {

   console.warn( 'THREE.OrbitControls: .dynamicDampingFactor has been renamed. Use .dampingFactor instead.' );
   this.constraint.dampingFactor = value;

  }

 }

} );
</script>
```

When the tween is completed and the controls of camera return enabled the rotation of camera not respect the pivot center of element but follow to take as center the old element position....

Anybody can help me?

Thank's a lot!

```
enter code here
```

Comment: You mean this? `controls.target = sphere.position; scene.add( sphere );`

Comment: I think not, how you can see on my fiddle, after the sphere moving the rotation whit mouse move is not correct, the center of rotation is still on the center of view...

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Off course! but the cam position turn to be centered and i don't have what i want, that is a little margin from the center of camera view